# zte/P892T57_MPCS/draconis:4.4.4/KTU84P/20161104.105951:user/release-keys

Tags: android

I have following crash on some devices. I see it on google play developer console. I searched over stackoverlow. But not found a solution. How I can solve this? And there is no error message. Whats is wrong here?

```
   *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'zte/P892T57_MPCS/draconis:4.4.4/KTU84P/20161104.105951:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 21508, tid: 21513, name: GC  >>> com.luckydeveloper.apkshare <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 41c0c87c  r1 00000080  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    r4 41c0c87c  r5 41c0c878  r6 00000000  r7 000000f0
    r8 41629d6c  r9 41629d6c  sl 41c0c870  fp 4012d2ec
    ip 00000000  sp 715c9d40  lr 400f0018  pc 40102a78  cpsr 60020010
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  746995497469c165  d5  7469c1a9746997c9
    d6  3e4ccccd00082a78  d7  42c800004a3a2520
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 65732f636f72702f  d17 2f6b7361742f666c
    d18 657361656c65723d  d19 3d6e69616d6f6420
    d20 5f657361656c6572  d21 6570797420707061
    d22 726f6674616c703d  d23 61645f7070615f6d
    d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 80000010

backtrace:
    #00  pc 00021a78  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
    #01  pc 0000f014  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
    #02  pc 0000f074  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
    #03  pc 000773eb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #04  pc 00058295  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #05  pc 0000d220  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #06  pc 0000d3b8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
    40102a58 e5900000 e2601000 e0100001 116f0f10  
    40102a68 12600020 e12fff1e e1a0c007 e3a070f0  
    40102a78 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e eafffff9  
    40102a88 e1a0c007 e1a03002 e1a02001 e3a01000  
    40102a98 e3a070f0 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e  
    40102aa8 e1a0c007 e1a02001 e3a01001 e3a070f0  
    40102ab8 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e e1a0000d  
    40102ac8 e12fff1e e92d50f0 e3a07025 ef000000  
    40102ad8 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
    40102ae8 ea006f84 f5d0f000 f5d1f000 e1500001  
    40102af8 13520000 03a00000 012fff1e e1a03000  
    40102b08 e352000c 5a000008 f5d0f020 f5d1f020  
    40102b18 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2 e050000c 112fff1e  
    40102b28 e2522001 1afffff9 e12fff1e e92d4010  
    40102b38 e3130002 0a000005 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2  
    40102b48 e2422001 e050000c 18bd4010 112fff1e  

code around lr:
    400efff8 e1a07002 ebfffe8b e5941000 e1a03007  
    400f0008 e1a02006 e2011001 e1a00004 ebfffd5f  
    400f0018 e1a04000 e1a00005 ebfffe41 e374006e  
    400f0028 03a0006e 13a00000 e8bd80f8 e3520000  
    400f0038 e92d4030 e1a05000 e24dd00c e1a04001  
    400f0048 0a000007 e1a01002 e1a0000d e1a02003  
    400f0058 ebfffd12 e3500000 b3a0006e ba000003  
    400f0068 e1a0200d e1a00005 e1a01004 ebffffda  
    400f0078 e28dd00c e8bd8030 e3a03000 eaffffea  
    400f0088 e3a02000 eafffffb e3a03001 eaffffe6  
    400f0098 eaffffd1 e304cdd3 e341c062 e92d4010  
    400f00a8 e1a0e002 e084329c e3043240 e340300f  
    400f00b8 e24dd008 e1a0200d e1a0c324 e3a04ffa  
    400f00c8 e58dc000 e06eec94 e0030e93 e58d3004  
    400f00d8 ebffffc1 e28dd008 e8bd8010 e5903000  
    400f00e8 e92d4070 e3130002 e1a04000 e1a05001
```

Comment: it looks a memory based error

Answer (score 1):

> pid: 21508, tid: 21513, name: GC  >>> com.luckydeveloper.apkshare <<<
>   signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

I think this means it crashed in the Garbage Collector (GC).  This is most likely to be the result of programing errors in JNI calls.  Like the GC started to collect something that isn't valid etc.  It could also be a memory allocation/deallocation problem in C code, or a problem with creating threads in C code.  The question does not give much info of the context of the crash, which you can get by putting some debug statements into the code around where the crash is occurring.